# Model Binding Complex Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

What I am trying to do is on one page have a FormView strongly typed with a nested ListView that also strongly typed.  The model hierarchy is ClassA(FormView) with a property of `List<ClassB>`.  This is for insert functionality.

I've attempted this many different was... for loop, asp:repeater, listview, when i click insert on the form view i can't figure out how to get to the collection of ClassB models. do i need multiple forms?

the interesting part is since these objects don't exists there could be any number of ClassB models.  I sticking with 5 for now but the user will define how many of ClassB they need before seeing this page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".